# Add separators in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a scenario where i have to add separators in DropDownList in asp.net. Please, suggest.

Comment: What did you mean by 'separator'?

Comment: @ban: I would imagine a horizontal line. Open any dropdown menu in your browser to see one.

Comment: It would help to see how you define & fill your list now. Databinding? Item tags?

Answer (score 19):

you can use disabled items as separators

example:

```
ListItem separator = new ListItem("---element---", "");
separator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
ddltest.Items.Add(separator);
```

Comment: Technically Your answer is correct. Not the one marked correct as it is ASP.Net related. Thank you for this tho it works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just add like this:

```
<asp:ListItem disabled>-------------</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much lighter-weight option:

```
<asp:ListItem Enabled="false">----------</asp.ListItem>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. However, Yipping's answer above did.